# Meteor js Как получить в переменную значение из MongoDB

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Начал изучать Meteor js и столкнулся с проблемой . Не могу вывести единственное значение из MongoDB. Постоянно приходит весь курсор с кучей не нужной информацией, а мне нужно именно значение переменной

Comment: Через toArray пишет `TypeError: User.find(...).toArray is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быстрее всего воспользоваться функцией [findOne](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-findOne)

User.findOne(...)

Если нужно из find получить значение, то нужно сделать fetch, при этом ограничив выдачу результата 1-м значением:

```
User.find(..., {limit:1}).fetch()[0]
```

Comment: А именно значение , т.к. выводится `id: ObjectID, animals: "doge"` . То есть я хочу что в переменной было само значение doge и я мог им пользоваться

Comment: User.find(..., {limit:1}).fetch()[0].animals

Comment: Можете привести кусок кода?

Comment: Вот:
`Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
 var first = User.find({},{limit:0}).fetch()[2].animals;
 console.log(first);
  },
});`
Сначало выдаёт ошибку, а потом само значение

Comment: Вы пытаетесь прочитать пользователей с лимитом в 0 записей, а потом пытаетесь взять 3-ю запись из массива прочитанных значений. Попробуйте исправить limit:0 на limit:1 и после fetch в квадратных скобках указать [0]

Comment: Без изменений... Только изменилось значение

Comment: А что выводит `Template.hello.helpers({ counter() { var allUsers = User.find({},{limit:1}).fetch(); console.log(allUsers);  return 0;}, });`

Comment: Выводит 2 курсора 
1:
`[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)
`
2:
`[{…}]
0: {_id: ObjectID, animals: "doge"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`
и 0 в main.html

Comment: То есть если вы сейчас запишите `Template.hello.helpers({ counter() { var oneUser = User.find({},{limit:1}).fetch()[0]; console.log(oneUser); return 0;}, });` должно вывестись {_id: ObjectID, animals: "doge"} без ноля.

Comment: Всё именно так ..Просит 15 символов оверстак

Comment: А если написать `Template.hello.helpers({ counter() { var oneUser = User.find({},{limit:1}).fetch()[0].animals; console.log(oneUser); return 0;}, });` то в консольку напишет просто doge

Comment: Да , но с ошибкой `Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'animals' of undefined
  `

Comment: Все так как нужно. В первый раз у вас нет в базе ничего, поэтому выводится ошибка. Во второй раз у вас уже есть запись в базе и вместо ошибки выводится значение.

Comment: `Template.hello.helpers({ counter(){ var oneUser = User.find({},{limit:1}).fetch()[0]; if(oneUser){ userAnimals = oneUser.animals; console.log(userAnimals);} return 0;}})`  Выведет только один раз doge.